# Middleman feed.xml.builder issues with iTunes tags

Tags: ruby, xml, rss, middleman, podcast

I need to be able to include iTunes style XML tags in my feed.

I see that you can make custom tags with `xml.<WHATEVER>` but what I need is support for `:` tags like in a podcast feed. `middleman build` pukes when you try something like `xml.itunes:summary` and `xml.itunes_summary` (like some gems use) doesn't convert to the `:` format.

Are these kinds of XML tags not supported or am I using the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice [Middlemanapp twitter account](https://twitter.com/middlemanapp/status/537747025559707648) directed me to the [Builder](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder) project which is the code actually doing the work.

If your goal is to get the namespaced, iTunes-y output like:

`<itunes:summary>The best damn thing ever.</itunes:summary>`

You can do it one of two recommended ways. I recommend the second way though because the first method adds a bunch of extra whitespace [as noted in this issue on Github](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder/issues/45).

`xml.itunes :summary { xml.text! "The best damn thing ever." }`

or

`xml.tag!("itunes:summary", "The best damn thing ever.")`